# compile AOSP failed in WSL with ftruncate(fd_out, GetSize()): Invalid argument

Tags: android-source, windows-subsystem-for-linux, android-8.1-oreo

[ 31% 19533/62179] Generating TOC: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar.toc
FAILED: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar.toc
/bin/bash -c "(ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0 prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ijar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp ) && (if cmp -s out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar.toc ; then rm out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp ; else mv out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar.toc ; fi )"
ftruncate(fd_out, GetSize()): Invalid argument
/bin/bash: line 1: 26539 Aborted                 (core dumped) ( ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0 prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ijar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v9_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp )
[ 31% 19534/62179] Generating TOC: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar.toc
FAILED: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar.toc
/bin/bash -c "(ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0 prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ijar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp ) && (if cmp -s out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar.toc ; then rm out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp ; else mv out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar.toc ; fi )"
ftruncate(fd_out, GetSize()): Invalid argument
/bin/bash: line 1: 26554 Aborted                 (core dumped) ( ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0 prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ijar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v21_intermediates/classes.jar.toc.tmp )
[ 31% 19546/62179] Protoc: out/target/product/rk3326_32bit...p-api.pb.c <= hardware/ril/librilutils/proto/sap-api.proto
[libprotobuf WARNING external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc:547] No syntax specified for the proto file: hardware/ril/librilutils/proto/sap-api.proto. Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";' to specify a syntax version. (Defaulted to proto2 syntax.)
[ 31% 19547/62179] Protoc: out/target/product/rk3326_32bit...p-api.pb.c <= hardware/ril/librilutils/proto/sap-api.proto
[libprotobuf WARNING external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc:547] No syntax specified for the proto file: hardware/ril/librilutils/proto/sap-api.proto. Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";' to specify a syntax version. (Defaulted to proto2 syntax.)
[ 31% 19556/62179] target Java: core-all (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-all_intermediates/classes)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
18:58:13 ninja failed with: exit status 1

failed to build some targets (48:39 (mm:ss))

Comment: it sems go wrong at ftruncate(fd_out, GetSize()): Invalid argument,how to solve it

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-build-rom-source-windows-10-t3469420/post70571884